# User insert data into specific cell in an HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to specify the coordinates of an HTML table cell, x and y? If it is possible, then how can a user insert a value into that specified cell by submitting a form? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, can you clarify?

Comment: You might need to reword this question. Is the form submitting to a database and then repopulating with the information from the database? Are you trying to accomplish it with only php and html because you can't use javascript? Are you not able to give the html element an ID name instead of finding the coordinates?

Comment: their is nothing to do with the position of the table cell ,index of that element in row will be helpful.

Comment: OK I will try to rephrase. I have a university project where I want to find out what numbers people add next to each other. So if in cell x1, y1 is number "1", what will be added in cell x1, y2? x2, y1? x2, y2? This is for pattern research. So I need a user to be alb to add an integer from 0-9 in a specified box. The table can be rather big.

Answer (score 0):

This [Reference](http://www.programming-web.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15%3ainsert-data-into-mysql-database-using-php&catid=4%3aphp-basics&Itemid=10) might help you... although you will have to do it explicitly as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question first. No it is not possible to set or get the X and Y position of a cell in a HTML table. Maybe you could explain a bit better what you actually want and I might be able to give you some advice.

Comment: OK I will try to rephrase. I have a university project where I want to find out what numbers people add next to each other. So if in cell x1, y1 is number "1", what will be added in cell x1, y2? x2, y1? x2, y2? This is for pattern research. So I need a user to be alb to add an integer from 0-9 in a specified box. The table can be rather big.

Comment: I'm sorry but you'll need to alter your question and try to give a better explanation then you're doing now. Try to draw a textual example of the table you are working with, and give an example of the code you have right now. If you do not have any code yet try to write down your program in pseudo code! If you want a good answer you have to aks a good question, put some effort into it!